# Is it possible to make DIV active by hovering instead of clicking?

Tags: javascript, html, css, hover

So, here is an example: We have 50x50 px sized DIV, it has black borders and white background. When you hover onto the div it changes it's background color to red.

Now the question is: when you have hovered once on the DIV, how can you make it's background color stay red, even if you move your mouse away?

In other words, how can you make DIV active by hovering instead of clicking?

Edit: Javascript is fine too, cross-platform solution would be preferred if possible.

Comment: javascript required for a change like that - is that an option?

Comment: Yes, edited original post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS solution will not work in all browsers, so you should use JavaScript. It would be better not to use DOM Level 0 events to do it as the other answer suggests, best practice is to add a class to your div that your CSS can style. You can use jQuery and do something like:

```
$(function(){    
    $('#myDiv').on('mouseenter', function(){
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

Then style it:

```
#myDiv.active {
    background: red;
}
```

This separates the structure, style, and functionality of your page, making it easier to maintain going forward. It also makes it easy to add the same functionality to other elements on the page.

Comment: "The CSS solution will nto work in all browsers, so you should use JavaScript" - this is a silly rule. It might work in all browsers you care about. Highlighting a `<div>` can only marginally be considered "functionality" (and it's up to the OP to decide whether it is), and as long as it's eyecandy I see no reason why not just have older browsers degrade to not having it.

Comment: I support the idea that we should develop something that works on all browsers, but until when we will always be handicapped because of IE6? IE6 or 7 are only available on Windows XP, even microsoft stopped or will stop supporting it, are we going to always ask our self if this works on IE6? Even major websites (Facebook, Google) barely works on IE6. (I'm still using Windows xp :P )

Comment: I think it's hard to make a good case that supporting IE9 is overly aggressive.

Comment: Your method looks great, but for whatever reason I can't get it to work. My jQuery library should be just fine. EDIT: doesn't work on jsFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/7eC3Z/) either, or maybe I'm just doing something wrong.

Comment: Sorry! The event should be 'mouseenter', not 'hover'.

Answer (score 1):

You should do like below:

```
   <div id="content" onmouseover="this.style.backgroundColor='red';"  > Testing div ... </div>
```

This is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mqZ8U/) to test it.

Comment: Neat, how would I load the styles from CSS file instead?

Answer (score 1):

For a Pure CSS Solution, you need to use transition.

```
div
{
     background:white;
     -webkit-transition:background 0s;
     -webkit-transition-delay:999999s;
     -moz-transition:background 0s;
     -moz-transition-delay:999999s;
     transition:background 0s;
     transition-delay:999999s;
}
div:hover
{
     background:red;
     -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
     -moz-transition-delay:0s;
     transition-delay:0s;
}
```

It will instantly become red `0s`, but would take `999999s` to become white, which is too much (you can increase it), I'm sure someone won't keep a page opened for hours, or days...

Comment: Nice hack, although I kind of feel like the vendor prefixed properties kind of clutter up the code sample. Personally I'd leave them out and rely on the person reading knowing enough about the current state of CSS to deal with them.

Comment: But keep in mind that transitions only work for some modern browsers.  Is the user looking for a "all-browser" solution?

Comment: @blachawk Seeing as the OP has expressed no such constraint, this answer remains perfectly valid.

Comment: Lately I'm sick of Javascipt, knowing that everything will not function if you disable Javascript makes me crazy, so I tend to use CSS for visual stuff, and use Javascript as minimum as possible. CSS3 is awesome!

Comment: @AliBassam To be entirely fair, it's about as fair to dismiss the users who insist on using legacy browsers as the users who insist on disabling JS. (And the point is particularly moot for eyecandy features.)

Comment: @blachawk Also, transitions are supported on IE10, which is available on Win7 now. I'd say reasonable to assume it as a baseline for new development now.

Comment: @millimoose I agree - its IE8 AND IE9 that I tend to have trouble with.  Sometimes I wish they just came out with IE10 and just skipped IE9.

Comment: I guess I should have been more precise when asking the question. I would rather like to also have it work in older versions of IE as well, thanks for the input though.